# Android to DjangoServer - Problems with Unique Identifiers for Users - hard code works, sharedprefs doesnt

Tags: android, python, django, string, sharedpreferences

Okay, here is my issue.  On first install on the Android I create a uniqueID for the phone(they look like this: 6458e138-76c3-8jf3-9708-69d701081cf1).  I then POST that id to the server and the server creates a user in my table.  That all works fine (ie, the user is created).  Now, the Android needs to use that uniqueID later and POST it to the server.  That is where the issue comes in.

I save the uniqueID as a string in my sharedPreferences.  When I grab the uID when I POST to the method mentioned above I receive a "no such user in database" from the server.  Now, if I replace that POST with a hardcoded string (of the same uID) it works! Where am I going wrong?

Here is my user MODEL in django (pretty simple):

```
class User(models.Model):

uniqueID = models.CharField(max_length=64)

def save(self,*args, **kwargs):
    super(User,self).save(*args,**kwargs)
```

Here is a snippet from one of my functions I POST to:

```
def getItems(request):
if request.POST:
    if 'uniqueID' in request.POST:
        try:
            userExist = MobileUser.objects.get(uniqueID = request.POST['uniqueID']) # checking if user exists...

            do things

            return HttpResponse(do things)
        except:
            return HttpResponse('no such user in database')

    other stuff
```

And just to make things clear, this (psuedo)code works:

```
String uID = "existing uID in table" 
POST_TO_SERVER(uniqueID = uID)
```

BUT this does not:

```
POST_TO_SERVER(uniqueID = MySharedPreferences.getString("uniqueID", "nouID")
```

(and printing mPrefs.getString("uniqueID", "nouID") shows the 'correct' id)

and for ultra completeness, this is how I enter the uID into my preferences:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor edit = MySharedPreferences.edit();

        edit.putString("uniqueID", uID);
        edit.commit();
```

Comment: I'd see what is actually being POSTed on the django side. Note that your `try/except` block could easily be hiding any exception at all and returning the message "no user"

Comment: Okay, when I POST (from the phone) I get a huge disgusting loop of an html document ... the error being "DoesNotExist at /url_suffix/" ... no idea why it is 'looping' like that (logcat shows all of the html flying by)

Comment: I'm not familiar with android but it would be odd if the exact same code on the phone is submitting to a different URL based on your input string. You should confirm whether or not this is a problem on Django or the Phone. If it's posting to a URL that doesn't exist, then you have to fix something on your phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found what was wrong...

I generate a uniqueID on the phone, then POST it to my server's register_user url.  The server then RESPONDS with the exact same uniqueID if things are successful.  I then save that RESPONSE uniqueID into my savedPreferences

The way I handle any response is get the inputStream of the response and then run it through this:

```
public static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line = null;
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

            sb.append(line + "\n");

        }
    } catch (IOException e) {


    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

And eventhough the response was only the uniqueID, I think this conversion to a string screwed something up in the process.

My fix was to just save the uniqueID to the sharedPreferences after I create it (instead of putting it there from the response).  Hope this can help somebody else down the line : )